# Prevent caching after page refreshes every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a news app. I refresh a `div` with the class of `.new_feed`  every 10 seconds, to check for new updates, and when there is it shows up. Now the problem is, when there is a new feed in it, and the 10 seconds is up, and you don't click to see, and wait for 40 seconds before you click,it brings up 4 records instead of 1. I think the problem has to do with caching.

#### Refresh script that gets the headline of the news

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
    setInterval(function() {
    $('.new_feed').load('headline.asp');
    }, 10000); 
});
```

#### Getting the feeds

```
$(function() {
    //More Button
    $('.more2').live("click",function() {
        var u_pic_id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (u_pic_id) {
            $("#more2"+u_pic_id).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "show_more.asp",
                data: "lastmsg="+ id, 
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("ol#updates2").append(html);
                    $("#more2"+id).remove();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="more2<%=(rs_ncount_id.Fields.Item("id").Value)+1%>" class="morebox2">
    <a href="#" class="more2" id="<%=(rs_ncount_id.Fields.Item("id").Value)+1%>">
        Load New Feeds
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should use [Incognito mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en "Setup directions for Chrome's Incognito mode.") for a fresh environment. Then [open the developer tools](http://anti-code.com/devtools-cheatsheet/ "Keyboard shortcuts for opening Chrome's developer tools.") and visit the [Network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance "Description of Chrome's Network panel."). You will see whether requests are being cached in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using HTTP header

You have to set the `Cache-Control` `HTTP/1.1` header at the server side. This is the recommended approach.

#### Using a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) in the request

However you can also use a hacky solution, if you can't change the server settings. Use a nonce in the request:

```
$('.new_feed').load('headline.asp?' + nonce);
```

Because it will look like a different request to the browser, it will ignore the cached value.

The simplest solution for a nonce is using the current time:

```
var date = new Date();
var nonce = date.getMilliseconds();
```

Comment: the load doesn't load

Comment: I didn't write the nonce generation part, so you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Please can u do it for me? I'm new to jQuery

Comment: @i_user:  Then this is a perfect opportunity for you to learn.

Comment: You just need to use a random string, the easiest solution is to use the current time. Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had an answer written up that pointed out the `cache:false` option for [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) but upon reviewing your OP I realized you were already using it. The documentation indicates the `cache:false` option will only append a timestamp on `GET` requests (and `POST` requests for IE8).

Since you're using a `POST` its unlikely the `cache:false` option is actually going to help (unless you're using IE8?). Instead, like @meskobalazs states you'll need to create and append a [nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce).

One way to implement this might be like:

```
function getValues(id) {
  var url = 'myUrl?id=' + id;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url + '&_=' + (new Date()).getTime()
  }).done(function(response) {
    // do stuff
  })
}
```

Of course if you have access to the server the appropriate way to handle this would be to correctly set the response headers. You may also consider using a more RESTful approach where the `GET` verb and route is used to request data.